# single call of `plot()` for plotting 3 separate plots in R?

Tags: r, matrix, plot

Suppose I have the following 3 matrices:

```
p.b7.4 = matrix(1:4, nrow = 2) 
p.b6.4 = matrix(1:6, nrow = 3) 
p.b5.4 = matrix(1:8, nrow = 4)
```

Further suppose, I divide my graphical device in 3 *particularly ordered* pieces:

```
m = matrix(1:3); layout(m)
```

**Question**

I'm wondering, at this point, if there is a way I could use a single `plot()` call to plot these 3 matrices above in my graphical device?

**NOTE:** This means I want 3 separate plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the 3 separate plots using a `lapply()`:

```
lapply(list(p.b5.4, p.b6.4, p.b7.4), plot)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you mean something like this?:

```
plot(p.b7.4,xlim=c(1,10),ylim=c(1,10),col="red",pch=16,cex=2)
  points(p.b6.4,col="blue",pch=16,cex=2)
  points(p.b5.4,col="green",pch=16,cex=2)
```

[image]